# How to dynamically update EurekaInstanceConfig's metadata before initial registration?

Tags: java, spring, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to write a configuration class that scans for some classes, generate some metadata about them and update EurekaInstanceConfig object's metadata map so that it gets sent to Eureka Server. The constructor of my configuration object injects the EurekaInstanceConfig bean initialized by Spring and does above operations within the constructor.

This is a single instance Spring Boot 1.5.21 application which works fine on my localhost. I'm able to see the metadata on Eureka Server. However when I deploy this onto my dev environment (where I'm running a Docker Swarm cluster with 3 instance Eureka Server setup), I can see that the constructor processes metadata (through the logs of my app) but no metadata exist on Eureka Servers.

I suspect that the metadata may get sent before my constructor finishes its work but that would mean that the registration happens before application context is fully loaded. Is that true?

Is it possible to update EurekaInstanceConfig's metadata after Spring created that bean and before it gets sent to Eureka Server?